# $\sqrt{-g}$ under orientation/time reversal

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I want to check whether $\sqrt{-g}$, $g = $ det$g_{\mu\nu}$ picks up a minus sign under time-reversal $t \rightarrow -t$, which reverses the orientation of the manifold. I've been reading a lot of se answers and lecture notes about scalar and pseudoscalar densities, and most of them seem to imply that $\sqrt{-g}$ is a genuine scalar density, so should not pick up a minus sign? But some places (eg p24 of [these notes](https://ccom.ucsd.edu/%7Ectiee/notes/tensors.pdf)) would imply to me that it does pick up a minus sign. And certainly I would expect $dt \wedge dx^1 \wedge \cdots$ to change sign, so $\sqrt{-g}$ would need to cancel that?

Could anyone give me a categorical answer of what happens to $\sqrt{-g}$ when $t\rightarrow -t$?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try calculating what happens to $g$ for a particular metric, such as the Minkowski metric, when $t\to -t$?